# Scrapy with Selenium - missing element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

Im running this code to extract information from a website using selenium through scrapy:

Extract:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from price_scraper.items import PriceScraperItem
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class NetcomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "netcom"
    #allowed_domains = ["https://shop.netcom.no/mobil/cmobil.html"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://shop.netcom.no/browse.ep?cID=10001&filters=cmobil_NetComNO_B2C&pn=1&sorter=featuredProducts-desc',
    )
    page = 2
    first = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.close()


    def parse(self, response):
      base_url = 'https://shop.netcom.no'

      for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="grid4 "]/div/h2/a'):
        item_url = item.xpath('@href').extract()

        self.driver.get(base_url + item_url[0])
        items = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@name="subscription"]')
        for item in items:
            print "test"
            # This step stops the process cannot get a new site so item is not clickable
            item = WebDriverWait(self.driver,20,poll_frequency=.2).until(EC.visibility_of(item))
            item.click()

            i = PriceScraperItem()
            name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1').text
            brand_name = name.partition(' ')[0]
            product_name = name.replace(brand_name, "")
            i['brand_name']          = brand_name
            i['product_name']        = product_name
            i['subsription_name']    = item.find_element_by_xpath('ul/li/span[@class="subscription-title"]').text
            i['subscription_price']  = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@name="monthlyPrice"]').text
            #i['lease_price']         = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@name="financingPricePerMonth"]').text
            i['upfront_price']       = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@name="payNowTotal"]').text
            i['total_price']         = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@name="minimumTotalCost"]').text
            i['date']                = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
            i['time']                = time.strftime("%H:%M")
            yield i

      if self.first != response.xpath('//div[@class="grid4 "]/div/h2/a/@href'):
        response.xpath('//div[@class="grid4 "]/div/h2/a/@href')
        self.first = response.xpath('//div[@class="grid4 "]/div/h2/a/@href')[0]
        print self.page
        url = 'https://shop.netcom.no/browse.ep?cID=10001&filters=cmobil_NetComNO_B2C&pn=' + str(self.page) + '&sorter=featuredProducts-desc'
        req = scrapy.Request( url, callback=self.parse)
        self.page += 1
        yield req
      else:
        print response.xpath('//div[@class="grid4 "]/div/h2/a/@href')[0]
        print self.page
        #raise CloseSpider('Finished all pages')
```

**Edit:** It seems like it was item.click() that made the script fail not `['lease_price']`. And it seems to fail because selenium is no longer doing any more requests. So even now that i have added "WebDriverWait" it eventually times out. Is there some gotcha here that i have missed?

Also i have added the complete class now.

Comment: Why did this question get down-voted?

Comment: It shouldn't stop the crawler, can you post your full class?

Comment: Ole, thanks for posting your full problem. I looked at the website and it seems that it can be handled without using selenium by simulating the ajax requests. Anyhow, its 3AM here so I'll write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Btw, I couldn't help but notice that you are setting your `item` variable to a `WebDriverWait` object (and not an element of the dom) so obviously `item.click()` would fail. Get rid of the assignment as its not needed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to look into which exception it throws up then catch it in a try-except block. From your description it seems like it should be the following

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from scrapy import log
try:
    i['lease_price'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@name="financingPricePerMonth"]').text
except NoSuchElementException:
    log.msg("No Lease Price for {}".format(response.url))
    i['lease_price'] = 0
```

More importantly, the exception should not stop the crawler. Scrapy usually dumps the traceback into the logs and proceeds with the next request in the queue. Can you post your code so I can investigate?

---

In your code, you are reassigning `item` to a `WebDriverWait` object and clicking on that, which is bound to fail, change it to

```
    items = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@name="subscription"]')
       for item in items:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver,20,poll_frequency=.2).until(EC.visibility_of(item))
        item.click()
```

And report back. I'll back tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have changed my code to exacly match yours, however the problem is still there. No new page is loaded in Firefox and after 20 seconds the script times out. do you have any idea why this might happen? Does it happen if you run the script?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that it might be possible to do this without selenium and i would love to get rid of selenium. But i can't seem to find how the page changes og gets the data stored in for example `//span[@name="payNowTotal"]`. It does not seem to get the data via xhr request. Can you see how the data is received?